# Setting background to uitabbar not wroking properly

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

[image]

Hi all, I am trying to create my custom tab bar like the above picture. Basically, a center raised tab bar, I have tried by setting a background picture, it's not looking proper. It always shows a line on top of the image and it's not filling the width. Below is the code for setting a background image.

```
    let image   = UIImage.init(named: "bottombar")
    if let image = image {
        let centerImage: Bool = true
        var resizeImage: UIImage?
   //     let height = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height ?? 49.0

        let size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 98  )
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        if centerImage {
            //if you want to center image, use this code
            image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: (size.width - image.size.width)/2, y: 0), size: image.size))
        }
        else {
            //stretch image
            image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size))
        }
        resizeImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        tabBar.backgroundImage = resizeImage!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

    }
```

Since the above solution was not working, I have tried to draw it using cashapelayer, and kept a center button on all viewcontrollers. Now the buttons are behind the layer it's not visible. Below is my custom tabbar class.

```
class CustomizedTabBar: UITabBar {

public var shapeLayer: CALayer?

private func addShape() {
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = createPath()
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
 //   shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.init(white: 0.8, alpha: 1).cgColor
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    shapeLayer.fillMode = .both
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0

    if let oldShapeLayer = self.shapeLayer {
        self.layer.replaceSublayer(oldShapeLayer, with: shapeLayer)
    } else {
        self.layer.insertSublayer(shapeLayer, at: 0)
    }
  //  self.shapeLayer?.contents = UIImage(named:"bottombar")?.cgImage
    self.shapeLayer = shapeLayer



}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    self.addShape()
}

func createPath() -> CGPath {

    let height: CGFloat = 37.0
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    let centerWidth = self.frame.width / 2

    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)) // start top left
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth - height * 2), y: 0)) // the beginning of the trough



    // first curve down
    path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: centerWidth, y: -40),
                  controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth - 30), y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: centerWidth - 35, y: -37))
    // second curve up
    path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth + height * 2), y: 0),
                  controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: centerWidth + 35, y: -37), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth + 30), y: 0))

   //  complete the rect
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: self.frame.height))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height))
    path.close()

    return path.cgPath
}

override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    let buttonRadius: CGFloat = 35
    return abs(self.center.x - point.x) > buttonRadius || abs(point.y) > buttonRadius
}
```

Please shed some light to acheive this tabbar. Help much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try this: https://github.com/eggswift/ESTabBarController